# How did Django send_mail work without EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD?

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

I tested Django `send_mail()` function which I needed for a project. I had the `EMAIL_HOST` set to the SMTP server provider my company uses, `EMAIL_PORT` to 587, `EMAIL_USE_TLS` to True. Both `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` was set to "" (empty string).

Then I used the `send_mail` as:

```py
from djanog.core import mail


mail.send_mail(
    "Django mail sample",
    "Body",
    "myemail@example.com",
    ["myemail@example.com"]
)
```

But calling the view actually sent the email to my mail from my mail, but I didn't provide any password at all. I also set `recipient_list` to my colleague's mail, it worked. Then I tried to change the `from_email` to my colleague's mail it didn't work.

I have my mail setup in Thunderbird in my system.

So how did Django sent the mail without my email's password? Was it because of my setup in Thunderbird? What happened exactly?

**Update:**

1. My colleague tried the same in his system, which doesn't have any mail configured. When running the result was an `SMTPRecipientsRefused`.
2. I used both my Phone's network as Hotspot and my company's Hotspot both worked. But in my colleague's system nothing worked.
3. When setting `EMAIL_USER_HOST` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` in my colleague's system it worked.

Comment: I'd recommend to check your SMTP server's configuration. Your IP address might be whitelisted to send mails from your e-mail address without further authentication.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I used my Phone's network though.